# How control web request C#

Tags: c#

I have this Handler that processes multiple data changes in a short period of time, How can I regulate how often the data is sent. I have several slider/ dragging functionality on the UI so if the User drags the mouse it moves the position of the car on the screen through a web rest api.

I would like to control it so instead of sending thousands of values per millisecond I would like it to be the last value every 100 milliseconds.

so if the value is at 0 and the user drags the mouse to 100 in 100 millisecond I would like to send 100 to the API instead of all the values in between.

Each property has a unique ID so I wanted to cache the values and send every 100 millisecond.

```
private void Car_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Position")
    {
        dynamic car = sender;

        var temp = (Car)car
         TestCache.cache.Set(temp.GUID, temp.Value); //
        temp.SendDataToAPI();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into "debouncing". It's a technique to limit the number of requests when events happen very quickly one after the other.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă have you got an links to good examples and is debounce suitable for if the user can also type to change the value??? So the can type, slide or drag